Are there any faster rolling window regression packages in R?
This question comes up regularly, especially in the context of finance where one wants to calculate rolling exposures to factors, but there seems to be no answer.  There are a number of R packages, but all of them seem only to be syntactic sugar rather than designed to be speedier for the special case of linear regressions.  For example,
################################################################
## neither runner nor roll.reg speeds up sequential regressions.
################################################################

N <- 100

set.seed(0)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(N))
y <- 3 * x + rnorm(N)

y[N/2] <- NA

df <- data.frame(y, x)

################################################################

## naive
slope <- rep(NA, 40)
norunner <- function() {
    for (j in 2:nrow(df)) slope[j] <- coefficients(lm(y ~ x, data = df[1:j,]))[2]
    slope
}

library(runner)
withrunner <- function() {
    slope <- as.numeric( runner( df, function(x) { coefficients(lm(y ~ x, data = x))[2] } ) )
    slope
}

library(fDMA)
withroller <- function() {
    with(df, roll.reg( y=y, as.data.frame(x=x), window=nrow(df))$coeff.[,2] )
}

################################################################
R <- 100  ## repeat for timing purposes

print( system.time( lapply( 1:R, function(i) norunner() ) ) )

print( system.time( lapply(1:R, function(i) withrunner() ) ) )

print(system.time( lapply( 1:R, function(i) withroller() ) ) )


takes about 2.2, 2.2, and 4.3 seconds on my hardware. There used to be a package rollRegres but it has been removed from CRAN.  RIP.  (I have not tried the GitHub release yet...is it really faster?  What made it be removed?  Is anyone still running it?)
Linear regressions should be rollable, as demonstrated e.g. by Gentleman's updating algorithm AS 274.  (Observations are deleted by weighting them with -1.)  Is something based on this or another algorithm available on CRAN for R?

This doesn't seem to be a rolling windiw problem. Just fitting a bunch of linear models. Best I could advice is to use fastLm Rcpp or simply do a quick implementation in fortran , which sometimes seems to be faster than even C/CPP in numerical computations

This doesnt seem to be a rolling window problem. You are increasing the data. Since you are using 1d, you could simply do:
v <- function(){
  i <- !(is.na(x)|is.na(y))
  X <- x[i]
  Y <- y[i]
  a <- cummean(X)
  b <- cummean(Y)
  n <- seq(Y)
  (cumsum(X*Y) - n*a*b) /(cumsum(X*X) - n*a*a)
}

This should return the same vector as your solution above.

thanks, yes, I knew.  I just wanted to make the example short.  all these packages also have a non-expanding window mode.

The answer turns out to be...library(roll).
library(roll)

withplainroll <- function() {
    with(df, coefficients(roll_lm(x, y, width = nrow(df), min_obs =1))[,2])
}

print( system.time( lapply( 1:R, function(i) withplainroll() ) ) )


and the speed now is 0.05 ... awesome --- but it uses all of my 8 CPU cores, so a fairer comparison is 0.5 --- still much faster.  thanks, Jason Foster.
